# How do I know where a control will be docked, and how do I prevent the docking?

Tags: delphi, vcl, docking

I’m using Delphi’s 'regular' docking (with DockSite = True and UseDockManager = True).  Now there’s several DockSite controls, and several dockable forms.  However, not each dockable form is supposed to go in each dock site.

The forms know what kind of control they’re supposed to dock onto; the controls, OTOH, don’t know what form to accept or not.

My problem, now, is that there’s several events going off where you can cancel a drag/drop (or drag/dock) operation: DragOver, StartDock, etc.  But those all occur on the 'receiving' side, never on the side of the control that’s being dropped; and that’s where I’d like to have it — so that the form being docked can refuse being docked to a certain control.

Is there such an event, am I overlooking something, or would I have to tackle this in a different way?

Comment: If set up correctly, cancelling the dock on either side should work fine.  Is there a reason why the destination refusing the dock is not working for you?

Comment: I want the forms to be as 'pluggable' as possible, and contain all the necessary logic (and references to business classes); but I’d like to keep the destination controls free from any knowledge about the forms they’ll contain. In the future, I might need to add new (classes of) dockable forms.

Comment: Can't you use a base class for your dockable forms?  That would significantly reduce the footprint for the controls.

Comment: I know this is possible in the extended docking features provided by the JVCL Jvdocking controls.

Comment: @JerryGagnon: How does using a base class reduce the footprint for the docking controls?

Comment: @WarrenP: ...but not Delphi’s standard docking?  Pity, I’d rather not have to change control sets at this point.

Comment: What I meant was that by using a base custom form then all the controls would need to know is how to work with that one form, regardless of what else might be added to it later or a descendant.

Comment: @JerryGagnon: so basically, I’d have to have all the docking controls ask the (base) form whether it should accept the incoming form.  Since it would appear Delphi’s standard docking doesn’t allow it in another way, I guess I’ll have to go with this.  Thanks!

Comment: Martijn; It extends the classes that are already in the VCL. In short, it provides the advanced functionality you are looking for that requires *subclassing*, not really replacing, the VCL docking code.

Comment: @WarrenP: hm... In that case, I might take a look at it.  Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured I should add this as an answer instead of just a comment.  Create a base form for your custom forms and put your logic in that.  Then each control would simply have to know how to interact with one form class.  Each new docking form you make would have to descend from this base form.  The beauty of this is that you will not need to make custom versions of your controls since everything can be handled through the standard event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

The `OnStartDock` event is fired for the control/form that is being docked, not for the DockSite control that is being docked onto.  So you can assign an `OnStartDock` event handler to your dockable forms, or better override the virtual `DoStartDock()` method.

Comment: `OnStartDock` is fired as soon as a control is started to be dragged. It is the OnStartDrag counterpart of a control when DragKind is dkDock. There's no hint then where the control is going to be docked to.

Comment: Like Sertac says: `OnStartDock` is fired before the target control is known. And I can find no way to detect it from inside the `DragDockObject` either: its `DragTarget` property reads and writes directly to the field, so there’s no method I could override.